# How to convert a broadcast stream to a single subscription stream in Dart?

Tags: dart

How do I convert an existing broadcast stream to a single subscription stream in Dart?

I want to avoid adding multiple listeners by accident.

Comment: I suppose you could do something like `Stream<Something> singleSubscriptionStream = () async* { yield* broadcastStream; }();`, and only expose the `singleSubscriptionSteam` object.

Comment: You can't mutate a `Stream` from single subscription to broadcast or vice-versa.  [`Stream.asBroadcastStream`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-async/Stream/asBroadcastStream.html) doesn't change an existing `Stream`; it creates a new broadcast `Stream` that passes along events from the original.  Going in the reverse direction wouldn't help prevent other listeners from being added to the original.

Comment: Furthermore, broadcast streams and single-subscription streams behave differently with regard to when events are fired, and a single-subscription stream listening to a broadcast stream could end up buffering an unbounded number of events.